# List not showing toggle correctly in HTML5

Tags: html, ionic-framework

i want to list items with a imagen on the left and a toggle in the right.

This is my result:

[image]

**As you can see, the toggle is on the left not on the right like the image below. This is what I need to fix**

I want to get this result (Call Ma):

[image]

But with a toggle instead of "telephone-outline" icon.

So.. This is my HTML:

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="cancha in vm.canchasComplejo"  class="list card">
      <ion-item class="item-stable"
                ng-click="vm.toggleGroup(cancha)"
                ng-class="{active: vm.isGroupShown(cancha)}">
          <i class="icon" ng-class="vm.isGroupShown(cancha) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
        &nbsp;
        Group
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="opcion in cancha.opciones"
                ng-show="vm.isGroupShown(cancha)">
          <div  class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" >
              <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
              Option
              <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
                  <input type="checkbox">
                      <div class="track">
                          <div class="handle"></div>
                      </div>
              </label>
          </div>    
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Could you tell me how to fix my problem?
Thanks

Comment: You should do it by css.

Answer (score 0):

Use item-toggle class. Below this sample code

```
    <div class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">
      <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
           Option
      <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! The icon show too small. Please see this image and you can see what I mean. We are too close! [link](http://imgur.com/a/tm4N7)

Comment: You can give font-size for large icon. <i style="font-size:50px" class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>

Comment: Yes but the icon not aligned with the other. Also the text starts before than the others. Set 50px is not a good solution.

Comment: 50 px is a sample. You should find optimum value